# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression when running Audit Trail module in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, syntax-error, audit-trail

I am trying to run an Audit Trail module on an Invoice form to keep track of changes. The same module works fine with several of my other forms, and my Invoice form doesn't cause any errors when I don't have the Audit Trail running. I am no expert and am not sure what to do to solve this! Here is the SQL for the form's record source, which is what causes the error:

```
    SELECT tblInvoice.*, tblAssignment.RateOut, tblTaskOrder.TaskOrderID, tblTaskOrder.TaskOrderName, tblPeople.PeopleID, tblPeople.[Firstname] & " " & [Lastname] AS FullName, tblVendor.VendorName
FROM (((tblInvoice INNER JOIN tblAssignment ON tblInvoice.AssignmentID = tblAssignment.AssignmentID) INNER JOIN tblTaskOrder ON tblAssignment.TaskOrderID = tblTaskOrder.TaskOrderID) INNER JOIN tblPeople ON tblAssignment.PeopleID = tblPeople.PeopleID) INNER JOIN tblVendor ON tblPeople.Vendor = tblVendor.VendorID;
```

And here is the Audit Trail module code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Const cDQ As String = """"
Sub AuditTrail(frm As Form, recordid As Control)
  'Track changes to data.
  'recordid identifies the pk field's corresponding
  'control in frm, in order to id record.
  Dim ctl As Control
  Dim varBefore As Variant
  Dim varAfter As Variant
  Dim strControlName As String
  Dim strSQL As String
  On Error GoTo ErrHandler
  'Get changed values.
  For Each ctl In frm.Controls
    With ctl
    'Avoid labels and other controls with Value property.
    If .ControlType = acTextBox Then
      If .Value <> .OldValue Then
        varBefore = .OldValue
        varAfter = .Value
        strControlName = .Name
        'Build INSERT INTO statement.
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO " _
           & "tblAudit (EditDate, RecordID, SourceTable, " _
           & " SourceField, BeforeValue, AfterValue) " _
           & "VALUES (Now()," _
           & cDQ & recordid.Value & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & frm.RecordSource & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & .Name & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & varBefore & cDQ & ", " _
           & cDQ & varAfter & cDQ & ")"
        'View evaluated statement in Immediate window.
        Debug.Print strSQL
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
      End If
    End If
    End With
  Next
  Set ctl = Nothing
  Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Description & vbNewLine _
   & Err.Number, vbOKOnly, "Error"
End Sub
```

Any ideas for me? TIA!!

Comment: I should add, the error only occurs when I make a change on the form, so it's definitely something to do with the Audit Trail...

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: What control name does the code stop on? The query looks OK. Does it run fine by itself?

Comment: The query was working fine as the record source for my form before I added the Audit Trail module in my form's BeforeUpdate event. But, the Audit Trail module runs fine and saves changes appropriately on several of my other forms. There isn't a specific line that pulls up with an error, I get a generic MS Access pop up when I try to make a change via the form that says "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression "'[above record source query here]'". 3075" I guess I should have said, it's definitely something to do with the interaction of the Audit Trail and record source query :\

Answer (score 0):

Your Audit Trail code has naive type conversion. Just tacking " characters on either end of the RecordSource string won't work *all* the time.

Current (wrong) quoted RecordSource value:

```
"SELECT ... , tblPeople.[Firstname] & " " & [Lastname] AS FullName, ... "
```

The problem is the `" "` in the middle turns it into *two* strings!

**Correct** value for Access SQL:

```
"SELECT ... , tblPeople.[Firstname] & "" "" & [Lastname] AS FullName, ... "
```

Now that the quotes are quoted, the insert will work fine.

To fix your code, do something like:

```
...
    & cDQ & Replace(frm.RecordSource, cDQ, cDQ & cDQ) & cDQ & ", " _
...
```

This is sloppy code, but you get the idea. You should do this for all string values you are inserting into the Audit Trail.